# Plot selected multiple rows fields for python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have an imported CSV data file for python plotting graph - the original dataset:
http://digitalchanhk.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/df_data.xlsx

While I would like to plot graphs -

1. Line Graph > Selecting the Sector (A) and Selecting Classes / Accommodation / Enrolment / Repeaters (Enrolment and Accommodation) and including the 5 years to view the trend, but I failed to do that by selecting multiple fields at different columns and using all the years as X axis.

Have tried like this but seemed not a good way to do:

```
school_data_enroll = school_data[(school_data['Sector'] == 'A') & (school_data['Classes / Accommodation / Enrolment / Repeaters '] == 'Enrolment') & (school_data['Classes / Accommodation / Enrolment / Repeaters '] == 'Accommodation')]
school_data_enroll.iloc[[0,1], [2,3,4,5,6]].plot()

plt.show()
```

Expected result[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SoIE.png)

2. Bar Chart > Selecting the (A, B) sectors at X axis and Selecting Classes / Accommodation / Enrolment / Repeaters (Enrolment) and only 2013 to 2015 data

Have tried like this but seemed not a good way to do:

```
school_data_enroll.iloc[[7,11,15], [4,5,6]].plot()

plt.show()
```

Expected Result][Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYdM5.png)

Anyone could have idea for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please share the code with us you've written to solve the question?

Comment: @medium-dimensional Thanks a lot! I have updated the code i have tried above, see if you can have idea for me to solve it

Comment: Could you please also copy and paste the data in the question instead of the image? Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Thanks! I have updated the dataset and also the expected result, see how could I improve this, while struggling how to select the data form the CSV file with horizonal years displaying, and selecting multiple fields at different columns and also looking for a good way to select the data to plot the graph instead of using .iloc numbers :(